# Can Predict/Classify be parallelized?

Tags: parallelization, machine-learning, high-performance-clusters

Being able to parallelize `Predict` /`Classify` would be useful on multiple fronts:

- Performance/Scale
- Streaming
- Pedagogical
- Scientific

*Performance-wise* such parallelization would enable the use of larger datasets and HPC resources; *Streaming-wise* parallelization would enable certain real-time, distributed, cloud applications; *Pedgagogically-wise*, parallelization could enhance insights into the structure and judicious choice of predicting/classifying `Method`s while *Scientifically*, fine-grained, customized parallelization could promote reproducibility, training variations, extensions of built-in classifiers and the creation of new, hybrid methods.

So are there good frameworks/strategies for parallelizing `Predict`/`Classify`?

Comment: Just as an observation, more than just parallelization needs to be addressed to make `Predict` and `Classify` good vehicles for machine learning research. The black box function approach, whilst good for a fast start, does not lend itself to tinkering, as far too little of the internals of the algorithms are exposed.

Comment: @image_doctor  It is possible to peer inside `PredictorFunction` and `ClassifierFunction`, which may be of help to both combine results of parallel evaluations of `Predict` and of `Classify` and to better understand and perhaps modify their numerical parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Since Version 11.x a new option is available for `Predict`, `Classify`, `NetTrain`:

```
TargetDevice -> "GPU"
```

If you have an NVIDIA graphics card, you can set this to achieve a big speedup in training. Ensure that you have a compatible NVIDIA graphics card and have installed the latest operating system drivers. Works with external GPU too. This guide might come handy for figuring out the GPU connectivity:

- [How-To-Guide: External GPU on OSX - how to use CUDA on your Mac](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1085633)